# How to prevent Azure WebJob from flooding Application Logs?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a WebJob deployed alongside the web application with Application Logging enabled (log level is set to Verbose). Every minute or so I get few big chunks of log entries similar to this one:

```
~1MY-SITE GET /azurejobs/api/functions/invocations/50b8a637-8717-4535-ab71-ee7d9af2a913/children limit=1&X-ARR-LOG-ID=d37aa32f-8fa7-4bae-aace-08d4a30ead04 443 - 37.122.166.46 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+Touch;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko ARRAffinity=68bd67b08e24ab020dd7d3d5cebe09fdf54a78d10dd6a9e876eb6c934e7d7fe2;+__RequestVerificationToken_L2F6dFJlam9icw2=GX2j_o3WZHpJX-ac_IjT8jOV_-nmz5Ry5k2qIA9BhoRJ1DguBqBXTvw1f7oJjxsN_byFrwLHE724-JjfSlAXyVhpCyBSFZ7a-8RV_eVbn0Y1 https://my-site.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions/invocations/20b8a633-8717-4535-ab11-ee7d9af2a958 my-site.scm.azurewebsites.net 200 0 0 721 1465 31
```

Since it is getting increasingly difficult to spot my own log entries among hundreds of these, I am trying to find a way to disable them - without much luck.

Is there a way to configure AzureWebjobs not to output these kind of log entries?

Comment: Duh, I realized this is not caused by a WebJob itself, but instead looks like a bug (or bad UX) in the new Azure portal: When "Application logs" are selected in "Streaming logs" blade, it actually shows both the application AND web server logs... When viewed in Visual Studio, these two types of logs are separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you are referring to in your question is an entry from a Web Server Log (IIS log), not an Application log. Either way, the short answer is no. Your log settings apply to both your web app and your web job.

If you're not senstive to costs then you could consider deploying your web job to a separate web app than the web app hosting your web front end.  That would keep your logs separate and also give you the flexibility to set logging levels independently between the two web apps.

Otherwise, it's really a matter of how best to sort through the logs to get what you are looking for.  [LogParser](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/910447/en-us) is the tool that is commonly used for querying Web Server logs.  It is a command-line tool and really useful for this sort of thing.  There's also a GUI tool ([LogParser Studio](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Log-Parser-Studio-cd458765)) on the Microsoft Technet Gallery that puts a nice UI around the tool. I've not used LogParser Studio personally (I prefer just LogParser) but from what I've seen it looks really nice.